# View still there but not visible after being moved out by animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a small but annoying probleme with animations on views in Android.

What is involved:
I have a FrameLayout in another FrameLayout contained in a xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/TopBanner"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/topmenu"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"></ImageView>

                <Gallery
                        android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>
        </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I also wrote an animation XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        fillEnabled="true"
        android:fillBefore="true"
        android:fillAfter="true">
        <translate
                android:duration="500"
                android:fromYDelta="0"
                android:toYDelta="-80%" />
</set>
```

What I want is to **translate on click** my inner frameLayout (topbanner) out of the activity view, except 20% of it, in order to make it re-appear when I click on it. A kind of top menu.

I managed to apply my animation, but even if **my layout is translated**, **I can touch it as if it was still there**. Any suggestion? Here is my java code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UserSettings = getSharedPreferences("net.blabla_preferences", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

        tab = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("net.blabla.FigureTab");

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_figure_list);

        final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation_topbanner);
        topbanner = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.TopBanner);


        topbanner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });

        load();

    }
```

Comment: For the animation write a animation listener [animation.setAnimationListener] and try changing the visibility of the topbanner to View.GONE when the animation ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Things have changed since the advent of 3.0 Honeycomb. There is a whole new animation system to take advantage of, take a look here: [Android Developer's Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29)

Animations do NOT effect the 'physical' location of the views on screen. If you want it to actually move then you need to adjust the properties of the view.

An easier solution for your situation would be to use the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) widget that is included in the SDK. Since you are trying to achieve a pull out menu this seems like a perfect fit.