# View still captures touche events after being moved

Tags: android

In my android app I have a view which is laid on top of another view. When I click a button this top view is animated and goes out of screen. The problem is that it is like the view is still "there" as it captures all touch events and they do not get passed to the view which is behind.

This is the code that animates the view away:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation (0, 0, 0, height);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
topView.startAnimation(animation);
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502580/view-still-there-but-not-visible-after-being-moved-out-by-animation

Comment: The solution proposed there is for Android 3+ I am using 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an animation Listener and remove the view from its parent when the animation is over.

```
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0 ,0);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                parentView.removeView(topView)
            }
        });
```