# How can I interact with animations?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have an animation that slides across the screen, while the animation is playing I want it to disapear if it has been clicked!

I have tried to use OnClickListener() and also OnClickMethods, both only work after the animation has finished playing!

```
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(answer,  answer, 0, height * -1); // xfrom , xto, y from,y to
    animation.setDuration(5000);
    Floater0.startAnimation(animation);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (AdPlayer0.isPlaying()) {

                answer = rn.nextInt(width) + 1; //useless
                TranslateAnimation animation0 = new TranslateAnimation(answer, answer, 0, height * -1); // xfrom , xto, y from,y to
                animation0.setDuration(5000);
                animation0.setFillEnabled(true);

                Floater1.startAnimation(animation0);
                Floater1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Floater0.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }
    });
```

I was reading the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502580/view-still-there-but-not-visible-after-being-moved-out-by-animation) and something interesting was mentioned:

> Animations do NOT effect the 'physical' location of the views on screen. If you want it to actually move then you need to adjust the properties of the view.

I have now tested the above quote, and it seems to be true! I have also looked into how to adjust the position properties of the view after the animation has ended, however I want to change its position before an animation has ended(While its playing)!

Any suggestions for a work around? ideally I would want to change the physical position of the view while the animation is played!

Comment: when button clicked, then check the animation status at that time?

Comment: @gvsharma, to test whether the button click is registered while an animation is playing, I created an OnClickListener that invokes animation.cancel() therefore when I clicked on the physical location of the view the animation cancels, but I want to enable the user to click on the view displayed by the animation

Comment: the only soloution I can think of so far is to change the properties of the view to match what the animation displays or to use another animation library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [TranslationAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) only moves the pixels on the screen, so an OnClickListener does not animate with it. Use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) instead and set an OnClickListener then it should work.

The code would look something like this :

```
Floater1.animate().setDuration(5000).translationX(answer).translationY(height * -1);
```

Check out all the available methods in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).

Edit/Update :

```
.translationX(float toX)
```

means -> animate the view to this point on the x axis.

The animation always starts at the current position of the view, so you don't need a fromX. There are also other methods which you can use :

```
 .translationXBy(float byX)
 .translationYBy(float byY)
```

With these you can translate the view **BY** the float value, and not **TO** a certain point on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, going to give it a shot now!

Comment: Thanks this resolves the issue, but I am trying to get the hang of it! How do I use it in this style animate().setDuration(5000).fromX().ToX().FromY().ToY() ?

Comment: Solved, it always started the animation from coordinates y(0)x(0), so I programmaticaly set the coordinates of the view then started the animation  Floater1.setX(answer); Floater1.setY(height);. Thanks a lot I was stuck on this for a day :)